# Using webworker to send a zipped file to main thread

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, postmessage

```
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
.then(function(content) {
    postMessage(content)
}, function(err){
})
```

I am developing a chrome extension and using JSZIp to zip files in a web worker thread. Since there is no way I can save the zip file in the web worker thread, I am trying to send the zipped files to main thread, but postMessage does not seem to work. The zipped file contains blob image files. How can I send the data properly?

Comment: Hey, I think your question is similar to this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746053/pass-large-amounts-of-data-between-web-worker-and-main-thread). See if it works.